# UnassignedReferenceException: The variable bullitPrefab of 'MoveAround' has not been assigned. Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity 3D from scratch.

**i am getting an error**

UnassignedReferenceException: The variable bullitPrefab of 'MoveAround' has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the bullitPrefab variable of the MoveAround script in the inspector.
UnityEngine.Object.Internal_InstantiateSingle (UnityEngine.Object data, Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/812c4f5049264fad/Runtime/ExportGenerated/Editor/UnityEngineObject.cs:44)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/812c4f5049264fad/Runtime/ExportGenerated/Editor/UnityEngineObject.cs:53)
MoveAround.Update () (at Assets/MoveAround.js:22)

**i am getting an error in the following code**

```
enter code here

var speed = 3.0;
var rotateSpeed = 3.0;
var bullitPrefab:Transform;

function Update ()
{

var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);

//Rotate around y - axis
transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed, 0);

//Move forward / bacward
var forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
var curSpeed = speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
controller.SimpleMove(forward * curSpeed);

if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
{
    var bullit = Instantiate(bullitPrefab, gameObject.Find("spwanPoint").transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}

}
```

@script RequireComponent(CharacterController)

here is the link of the tutorial 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfpZ7_aFoko&list=PL11F87EB39F84E292

Comment: "You probably need to assign the bullitPrefab variable of the MoveAround script in the inspector. "

tells you what you need to do right in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach the script to an object in Unity3d, you should see the public vars in the object explorer. Make sure you drag the bullitPrefab to that script, so Unity3d knows which prefab to use in `bullitPrefab`. It now says (None), but it should be `bullitPrefab`.